# Issue Working with CRUD for images and media files in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

**Scenario**

I need to store media files in my database as VarBinary and images as an nvarchar or VarBinary (undecided). I am using MVC5 and entity framework. I have already made a CRUD controller for another table in the database which does not contain media files or images and this is working correctly.

**What I have done so far**

I have created a categories controller which is as basic as controllers come as all of the datatypes for that table are text or numbers. I have replicated this design logic for my MediaFiles controller and Image controller, but I am lacking the knowledge to adapt this to handle converting this file and storing in the database for mediafiles.

**Model**

```
using System.Web;

namespace MediaOrganiser.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;


    public partial class Image
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Image()
        {
            MediaFiles = new HashSet<MediaFile>();
        }

        public long ImageID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<MediaFile> MediaFiles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MediaOrganiser.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MediaOrganiser.Controllers
{
    public class ImageController : Controller
    {
        IMediaRepository mediaRepository = null;
        public ImageController(IMediaRepository mediaRepository)
        {
            this.mediaRepository = mediaRepository;
        }
        public ImageController()
        : this(new SQLMediaRepository())
        {

        }
        // GET: Image
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        // GET: Image/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Image/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            return View(image);
        }

        // POST: Image/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Image im)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(im.ImageFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(im.ImageFile.FileName);
            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            im.FilePath = "~/Images/" + fileName;
            fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + fileName);
            im.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
            using (MediaEntities db = new MediaEntities())
            {
                db.Images.Add(im);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Image/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Image/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Image/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Image/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Create View**

```
@model MediaOrganiser.Models.Image

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Image", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Image</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FilePath, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <input type="file" name="ImageFile" required />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FilePath, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**What I want**

At the moment when I try to create an image I get the following error message:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet

I want to be able to create CRUD methods in C# to store the following in the database:

Name - nvarchar(255)

FilePath - nvarchar(Max)

I have follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5L5W-AE-sEs

Any help is very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark your property  `public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }` as `[NotMapped]`

```
[NotMapped]
public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
```

The same with all properties that should not be mapped and does not exist in DB table.

Comment: Resolved the issue. Knew it was going to be something this stupid! Thanks - marked as answer.